# Android: How i can implement the warning in a text field

Tags: java, android, text, field

How I can implement a warning in a text field like this in android:

[image]

Comment: Sudhanshu's answer is correct. But you should be aware of some shortcomings of this methods. You can read about them on my blog post: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/displaying-error-hints-in-forms-on-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use TextView.setError method.

```
textView.setError("Field can't be blank");
```

This will display error message as shown in the image with default error icon. You can even change the icon using the second variant of the setError method.

```
public void setError (CharSequence error, Drawable icon)
```

To clear the error simply pass null as the method argument.

```
textView.setError(null);
```

for more details check:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from using a Toast you could always use the new Crouton library:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/

Comment: Thanks, Laurence. But in this case, Sudhanshu's answer is correct. Croutons are great for general conditions but not field-specific. Even though Sudhanshu's answer is correct and should be voted as such, there are some shortcomings. See my comment directly below of the question.

Answer (score 0):

**-** You can use `Toast` to do this.

**See this link:**

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

**-** You can also use `AlertDialog` to do this.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

USe `Toast.makeText()` as below:

```
 try{
    .....
    ....
  }catch(NullPointerException ex){ //<--Exception when you want to show the message
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), 100).show(); 
  }
```

For validation messages:

```
  if(textFieldValue == null || "".equals(textFieldValue)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field can't be blank", 100).show(); 
  }
```

Comment: You should mark that the Exception should be very specific. To catch Exception in general is no good practice.

Comment: @rekire It was just for idea. I updated the answer with `NullPointerException` :)